# Convert Secret Variables to PSCredential

Tags: powershell

In my Release, I want to run a Powershell DSC script needing a PSCredential object. Are there any "clean" ways to convert a Secret Variable to a PSCredential object?

Currently I use:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $secretPasswordParam -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
```

and need to set `PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword` to `true`.

**Update:**

When running `Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer` I get:

```
PSAvoidUsingPlainTextForPassword    Warning      deploy.ps1 4     Parameter '$secretPasswordParam' should use
                                                                  SecureString, otherwise this will expose sensitive
                                                                  information. See ConvertTo-SecureString for more
                                                                  information.
PSAvoidUsingConvertToSecureStringWi Error        deploy.ps1 21    File 'deploy.ps1' uses ConvertTo-SecureString with
thPlainText                                                       plaintext. This will expose secure information.
                                                                  Encrypted standard strings should be used instead.
```

Because this messages and a not good feeling setting a explicit option named `PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword`, I search for a cleaner solution.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your current solution? Two lines of code is pretty concise.

Comment: What's the issue of your code? Provide the details of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the question with more info, why I  thinks it is not "clean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is not "clean", because the script analyzer just analyses that PS file, it can't analyse the script file with specific context.

Regarding secret variables of build/release, you can't output it as plaintext (e.g. Write-Output), unless you send it to a website and get the value.

Secret variables are:

- Encrypted with at rest with a 2048-bit RSA key.
- Not returned back to the client. They are automatically masked out of any log output from the build or release.
- Not decrypted into environment variables. So scripts and programs run by your build steps are not given access by default.
- Decrypted for access by your build steps. So you can use them in password arguments (for example Build and Deploy your Java application to an Azure web app and also pass them explicitly into a script or a program from your build step, for example as `$(password)`.

You can store the encrypted value (e.g. encrypted by a tool) in the variable if you don’t want others to get the actual value without the key.

More information about Secret Variables, you can refer to: [Secret Variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#secret-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I use ConvertTo-SecureString which receives a string variable type.  The parameter type is -AsPlainText -Force.   If you secret variable is not a string type than the cmdlet will fail